# Style column cell in a HTML table

Tags: html, css

I am working on an asp.net mvc 3 application. Here is print screen of the table column I want to style :

[image: Table column]

I'm sorry for the cyrillic. Each line in the cell is created with this code :

```
                @:<span class="TableColumn4">
                @field[i].QuestionText;
                @::
                @field[i].FieldValue;
                @:</span>
```

And the CSS is :

```
span.TableColumn4 {
    background: lightgrey;
    display: block;   
}
```

What I want is - as you can see everything is in the middle of the cell leaving a lot of empty space at the top and bottom of the cell. I want to make the text a little more even. I tried to add some `padding-bottom` in the CSS but it didn't to the job.

Comment: Can u simulate the same on jsfiddle

Comment: To be honest I have zero experience doing things in jsfiddle. It will take me too much time to recreate this.

Comment: jsfiddle is super easy and useful.  It's simply a matter of copy/paste for your html markup and css.  I highly recommend trying it out :).

Comment: yes @steaks, just go to http://jsfiddle.net and add your css in respective blocks. I would suggest you to use jsfiddle often very useful site :)

Comment: Most of the time I work on the backend. When I need to work on the UI I count mostly on google and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to make the space above and below the text smaller? It looks like something is making that table cell's height expand. Is there content to the left or right of the cell in question that is filling out the entire height of that row? There could possibly be a height applied to that row. Try adding `height:auto;` to the row and the cell.

Comment: it seems that height: auto; and line-height; in my case behave almost the same except when I set the line-height to something little like 3px.I don't know why padding is not working.

Comment: Is there any content in the cells to the left or right of the cell in question? I just have a feeling something is making that row expand.

Comment: Yes, as it's said in the original post the print screen is only of the column I like to style, and it's not even the column but that specific cell. There are four columns and the height of the row is determined by default from the highest cell which is not the one I've shown here. Actually it's the cell left from this one, but There everything is OK, but because that left cell is bigger than this I want to style the text in this cell to occupy the space more evenly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the CSS property "[line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)" will help you.  However, this seems like a very limited fix for one cell of an entire table.  If you could add your markup and CSS to a new [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), then it would be helpful toward coming up with a more elegant solution.

Also, if you want the background color to fill the entire cell (and not just where the text is) to avoid the white above and below the text, then you should apply the "background-color" CSS to a class on your "td" tag rather than span within the td.

Comment: No, the color is just... dunno it won't stay anyway. But it would be good if the space between the span tags can be adjusted. Line-height seems to be not working in my case.